# How to create a custom azure devops task from a .net core console app

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I would like to create an Azure Devops task based on a console app I have created.
The task should run on a Linux build agent, but I have no idea about how to get started.

Has anyone else done some things similar already?

Answer (score 1):

azure devops task is based on Node.js

from the following articles

- [Add a build or release task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/add-build-task?view=azure-devops)
- [Reference for integrating custom build tasks into extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/integrate-build-task?view=azure-devops)
- [How To Build An Azure Custom Build/Release Task](https://blog.ipswitch.com/how-to-build-an-azure-custom-build/release-task)
- [azure-pipelines-tasks samples](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/tree/master/Tasks)

you can know much about create a task.

The SDK of azure devops task is Node.
Maybe,You can combo the [DotNetCoreInstaller](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/DotNetCoreInstallerV0) and Github and other tasks.
But, the enviroment is Node.js

The easyest way is use Node.js.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct task handler for .NET core. In order to make a cross platform task, you'll therefore need to create a small typescript project that uses the azure-pipelines-task-lib to call your executable.

I've got a very simple extension which packages an executable here, which can serve as an example of the extension structure:

```
https://github.com/jessehouwing/azure-pipelines-agent-screenshot
```

You'll need to change the following things:

- vss-extension.json

  - publisher
  - extension id
  - contribution id
- task.json

  - task id (give it a new guid)
  - task name
  - remove the current executionhandler and replace it with the Node one.

A very simple task that runs `ping.exe` based on Typescript can be found  here:

```
https://github.com/jessehouwing/azure-pipelines-demo-ping-task/blob/master/PingTask/ping.ts
```

The simplest form would look like this:

```
import tl = require('azure-pipelines-task-lib/task');
import trm = require('azure-pipelines-task-lib/toolrunner');
import { chmodSync } from "fs";   

async function run() {
    try {
        let echoPath = tl.which('ping');

        if (!isWindows) {
            chmodSync(echoPath, "777");
        }

        let ping = tl.tool(echoPath);
        let result: number = await ping.exec();
    }
    catch (err) {
        tl.setResult(tl.TaskResult.Failed, err.message);
    }
}

void run();
```

All the basic steps to get your task bootstrapped are here:

- https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-task-lib/blob/master/node/README.md

Publishing a task to the marketplace is explained here:

- [How to test new Azure DevOps extension version before publishing it for everyone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56029313/how-to-test-new-azure-devops-extension-version-before-publishing-it-for-everyone/56029399#56029399)